# invertibility of a bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

> Is $T\in \mathcal{B}(F)$ and **bijective**, is $T$ invertible? i.e. is $T^{-1}\in \mathcal{B}(F)$?

Comment: One of the most basic theorem of Functional Analysis is Open Mapping Theorem and your question is answered by that theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is bijective, then $T^{-1}\in \mathcal{B}(F)$. This is a consequence of the open mapping theorem.

Comment: While I did realise the Banach-Schauder theorem proves it, how come my $T$ was not bijective? Anyway, I'll think about it.

Comment: @Fred Thank you for your answer. Please where is the problem in the following operator $$
M = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 \\ & \frac{1}{2!} \\ && \frac{1}{3!} \\ &&&\ddots \end{array}\right].$$ I think it is bijective and not invertible.

Comment: @WillM. This operator is compact, then its range is not closed, hence not surjective

Comment: Why it is compact? Thank you

Comment: Regardless the fact that $M$ is compact, it is trivial to check that it is not surjective. Just try to find $x$ such that $Mx=(1,1/2!, 1/3!.\ldots)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami For the benifit of the reader your comment can be an answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019728/proving-t-is-a-compact-operator-and-thus-has-not-a-closed-range since $M$ is surjective and has a dense range.

Comment: Done. $\ \ \ \ $